# Creating Stored Procedure Error Sybase

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in a Sybase database that is called in Java, and take input arguments that populates 2 separate tables; some arguments go into both, some go only into one of the tables.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
Create procedure dbo.ps_bau_insert (in userID varChar(8), in busReason varChar(800), in weekID Integer,
                                in qScript varChar(800), in success BIT, in rowsAffected varChar(100))

            BEGIN

            Insert into dbo.tbau_request_details 
            (weekID, userID, Date, qScript, BusReason, Success, Rows) 
            values (weekID, userID, getDate(), qScript, busReason, success, rowsAffected)
            Insert into dbo.tbau_request_cm
            (userID, Date, BusReason, Success, Rows)
            values (userID, getDate(), busReason, success, rowsAffected);
            End
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error report -
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.
```

As far as I can see (by looking at the sybase documentation) the syntax is correct; the error statement says otherwise. Can someone help me see what is incorrect here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Sybase ASE you need to have an AS before the BEGIN.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1520/html/iqrefso/X315708.htm refers to this:

> Syntax
>
> This subset of the Transact-SQL CREATE PROCEDURE statement is
>   supported in Sybase IQ:
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE [ owner.]procedure_name
>
> … [ [ ( ] @parameter_name data-type [ = default ] [ OUTPUT ] [ , … ] [ ) ] ]
>
> …[ WITH RECOMPILE ]
>
> … AS
>
> … statement-list